# ImportError: libjpeg.so.9

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, libjpeg

I have installed opencv in ubuntu. Now, when I am importing cv2,
there is an error

```
'ImportError: libjpeg.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'
```

How to fix the error ?
I have already searched net and tried some but couldn't resolve the error.

I have also tried the following :

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg9
```

The following is the output :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg9
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason your version of OpenCV has been oucompiled against http://ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v9b.tar.gz ... Either you should also compile and instlal that or you can recompile opencv with libraries that are on your system.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed Masud . Can you please guide me step by step , how to fix the error. I am new to this.